# Object reference exception when drag and dropping from toolbox to Windows Forms designer

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

When dragging a control from the toolbox and dropping it in the Windows Forms designer, a message box appears with the message **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

After closing the message box, I can drop the control on the form without any other issue.

This happens on a new project as well. The error appears in both VS 2015 and 2017 (both community editions).

**EDIT :** This happens on any control, including custom ones. This started happening after I updated to the latest version of Windows 10 (17134.48).

Comment: Which control are you dropping?

Comment: @LarsTech I edited my question with further details

Comment: What controls are currently on the form?  Does this happen on a blank form?

Comment: @LarsTech This happens on both existing and new forms and in existing solution and new one.

Comment: Well, something is borked.  Try rebooting the computer one more time to see if it goes away.  If it doesn't, then make sure your Visual Studios and .net libraries are up to date, too.

Comment: Start VS again, use Debug > Attach to Process and pick devenv.exe.  And Debug > Windows > Exception Settings, tick the checkbox for CLR exceptions.  Back to the first instance, trigger the error.  Post the stack trace in your question.

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks for the advice. Already done that and tried some other stuff on the internet, like deleting tbd files in the AppData.

Comment: @HansPassant I attached the debugger and tried to put the controls into the designer. No error was throw. I checked all options in the Exception Settings.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of dragging and dropping, Clicking on the control, then clicking on the form is the workaround working for me until they come out with a newer update.

This is new behavior as of Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.8.6 for me.

Hopefully this will help others that just kept dragging and dropping over and over like I was doing :-)

Comment: Can confirm this approach still works for Visual Studio 16.6.3, where the error appears when running VS on a high resolution monitor.

Answer (score 6):

Experiencing the same issue on Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.5.0. I found that I was not able to drag and drop controls while VS was open on my high DPI external monitor, but if I moved VS to my native laptop monitor, I was able to drag and drop the controls.

Comment: I had the opposite problem - I had started Visual Studio in /noscale (Automatic scaling turned off) mode. If VS was on the high DPI monitor, no problem. If VS on my 1920x1080 monitor, adding a control from the toolbox caused "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". Attempting to move any controls within a TabStrip using the mouse would see them go back to their original position when releasing the button (without any error message!)

Comment: I have 3 monitors and just moving to a different monitor fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

For Visual Studio 2017 I did not fix the problem, but I found a workaround:

- went to *C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_e3603226*
- deleted all **.tbd*, *privateregistry.bin**, *ApplicationPrivateSettings.xml*  files
- deleted all files in *ComponentModelCache* folder
- restarted Visual Studio as Administrator
- it showed a message of updating the MEF files
- drag and drop is **NOT** working. It keeps throwing the same error
- **BUT** I can click on the item I want in the toolbox and then click on the designer without dragging and it works.

For Visual Studio 2015 I did not fix the problem, but I found a workaround:

- went to *C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0*
- deleted all **.tbd*, **.lock*, *devenv.exe.config* files
- deleted all files in *ComponentModelCache* folder
- restarted Visual Studio as Administrator
- drag and drop is **NOT** working. It keeps throwing the same error
- **BUT** I can click on the item I want in the toolbox and then click on the designer without dragging and it works.

Comment: Hi @CristisS.  Did you end up finding a solution? I have the exact same issue.

Comment: @DavidArcher Unfortunately no. I didn't try reinstalling visual studio or Windows. I learned to live with it. Hopefuly, it will be fixed on another Windows update.

Comment: Thats a shame.  I'm learning to do the same.  I've tried a full Visual Studio repair, and re-installed all extensions but no joy.  If I come across a fix, I'll drop you a note. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I have also seen the same problem repeated today in Visual Studio 2019 (Today is June 27 2019). I am trying out the VS 2017 solution from CristisS (above). I have verified that the 'workaround' still throws the exception, however, you can immediately draw the tool onto the form.

Answer (score 2):

I repeatedly run into the same issue. Seems to always be caused by running the Windows Forms designer on my secondary monitor. I don't know what causes it to misbehave, but moving Windows Forms Designer window back to my laptop screen always fixes the issue. Idk if it has something to do with scaling, or what, but it is a very repeatable issue that needs to be addressed.

Comment: I just ran into this issue today. It's VERY strange!

Answer (score 2):

Moving Visual Studio over from my hi res secondary monitor to my primary laptop monitor did fix the issue.

To use Visual Studio on my larger secondary monitor, I set my secondary monitor from 3840x2160 down to 2560x1440 and **set scaling from 150% down to 100%**

This lets me Drag and drop from the toolbox to the designer in **Visual Studio 2019 (V16.11.3)** without issue again.

Comment: This is still an issue in 2022. I moved to my primary laptop away from hi res secondary monitor and it fixed this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found  two solutions, to this problem that they worked for my WPF project in VS2015

solution 1) Click on the icon "enable/disable project code" in the bottom of windows design(the last icon near the percentual of zoom)-->Put Disable.

solution 2) Dx mouse button on your file .xaml and apply your modify in blend , selecting the "Open in Blend..." menu.

That's all

Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

Old post but I hope this helps someone:

I found a solution that worked for me on Visual Studio Professional 2019: set the secondary monitor to 125% and drag and drop an item. Then set it back to 100% and the problem is fixed.